# Writing the results in html file by passing the values in java - any help would be greatly appreciated

Tags: java, html

[Placed the reports have overrided all the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtASR.png)i would like to print in a table with results but when i printed it overriding the results and it is printing only one line

am passing the values form other class file to print the results

i have tried using Buffered  writer for writing the code

```java
public void createTestSummaryHTMLTable(String sample,String samp[le,String sample,String passedText,String status) throws IOException {

    File file=new File("C:\\AutomationResults\\Forms\\",foldername);
    if(!file.exists()){
        file.mkdir();}  

    final String FILE_PATH =(file+"/"+formname);

    //final String FILE_PATH = "C:\\AutomationResults\\Forms\\"+formname;
    final String FILE_EXTENSION = "html";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd"); // add S if you need milliseconds
    String filename = FILE_PATH + "_"+ df.format(new Date()) + "." + FILE_EXTENSION;

    File file2 = new File(filename);

    // if file doesnt exists, then create it
    if (!file2.exists()) {
        file2.createNewFile();
    }
    BufferedWriter html = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file2));
    html.write("<html><body bgcolor='#E6E6FA'><table border=1 cellpadding=0>");
    html.write("<title>Automation Summary report </title>");
    html.write("<br>");
    html.write("<center><strong><em>Batch report heading</em></strong>");
    html.write("<span style ='float; right;position:relative;right:30px;font weight:bold'>"+new Date().toString()+"</span>");
    html.write("<tr>");
    addlabel1(html,"Test Step Name");
    addlabel1(html,"Test Step Description");
    addlabel1(html,"Status");   
    addlabel1(html,"Screenshot");
    html.write("</tr>");

    html.write("<tr>");
    html.newLine();
    addlabel(html,sample);

    addlabel(html,sample);

    String status1 = "Passed";
    if (status1.equals(status))
    {
        html.write("<td width='20'style='color:#00F00;font-weight:bold;text-align:center'>"+status+"</td>");
    } else {
        html.write("<td width='20'style='color:#A52A2A;font-weight:bold;text-align:center'>"+status+"</td>");
    }

    addlabel(html,"Screenshot");

    html.write("</tr>");
    html.write("</table></body></html>");
    html.close();
}
```

Comment: This is very unclear. Excluding the header, why would you expect it to write more than one line into your table? You have only one print statement which will vary based upon the if and no loop.
Pls provide sample inputs, expected outputs.
Can you provide examples of what you have done so far? 


Please refer to
[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and
[create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I was looking at your code, were these parameters `String sample,String samp[le,String sample` duplicated on purpose?

Comment: Hi I have changed the parameters..I need to print the 4 values..test step.test step description and status and screen shot..this is an passing from somother file to print here

Comment: @gmc..do I need to use the loop.because am not storing in any variable here ..I am getting the values from some other class file am just writing to HTML table ...

Comment: can you please give an example of what your output is expected to be? your comments to both answers below conflict with your example above. your example above writes a complete html document @CodingLife has guessed that you want to append to the file - his/her answer achieves that. please provide more details to make it easier to help you.

Comment: in reply to your comment "i need to print the 4 values, just put 4 ```html.write("<tr>....</tr>\n");``` lines, 1 for each value. or if you want one row with 4 columns, use 4 prints of "<td>...</td>" again, one for each value.

Comment: what does addlabel do? maybe you need to move the addlabel lines up into your "<tr>" that is otherwise not being used?

Comment: HI thanks for your replies. my problem is when i called the "createTestSummaryHTMLTable"  form another class it is displaying the headers for all the time am calling the createTestSummaryHTMLTable method. but i dont like to print the headers all time it should be printed only one and rows should be append on everytime i print

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I think i guessed your problem. The file written is a single long line.

That is because write only writes what you give it. You need to put a \n at the end of all your strings.

Alternatively, use Printwriter's println method to output to your file.

Comment: Hi no it's not a long line...it's overriding the results printed and it is printed only one line..I have many  rows to print ..but it is printing only one line

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a boolean parameter to `FileWriter` that helps to specify whether it should append to or override the existing content. If you pass true, it would open the file for writing in append mode.

Please change this line:

```
BufferedWriter html = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file2));
```

To this:

```
BufferedWriter html = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file2, true));
```

Comment: hi now it is displaying all the results but with the header for all the rows.. but i need to print the header onlyonce and rows should append.

Answer (score 0):

the actualresult

[header is displaying for every row i dont need the header to display for all the rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAefP.png) result am getting is 
expected result is

header should display only once

Comment: Any help for above image would be greatly appreciated